Time needed to observe $k$ events in a Poisson Process?
Consider a Poisson process.
Let $N(t)$ be the number of events that have occurred up to time t. Then, for any time interval $(t, t+h]$, the probability of k events occurring in this interval is given by the Poisson distribution:
$$P(N(t+h) - N(t) = k) = \frac{e^{-\lambda h}(\lambda h)^k}{k!}$$
Where:

$\lambda$ is the rate parameter
$h$ is the length of the time interval
$k$ is the number of events (k = 0, 1, 2, ...)

I am interested in trying to answer the following two questions:

Question 1: Using the expected value, we can find out the expected number of events that is likely to happen by some time $T=t$. But what is the variability of this number?
Question 2: On average, how much time needs to pass such that there will be a $p_1$ probability of observing $k$ events?

For Question 1, I think all we need to do is find the variance of a Poisson Process. There are probably many ways to do this, but I did this using MGFs.
We can write a Poisson Process $N(t)$ in terms of a Poisson Distribution:
$$P(X = k) = \frac{e^{-\mu}\mu^k}{k!}$$
$$N(t) \sim \text{Pois}(\lambda t)$$
$$P(N(t) = k) = \frac{e^{-\lambda t}(\lambda t)^k}{k!}$$
From here, we can define the MGF for a discrete random variable X:
$$M_X(s) = E[e^{sX}] = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} e^{sk}P(X = k)$$
Applying this to our Poisson process:
$$M_{N(t)}(s) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} e^{sk} \frac{e^{-\lambda t}(\lambda t)^k}{k!}$$
$$M_{N(t)}(s) = e^{-\lambda t} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(e^s \lambda t)^k}{k!}$$
This sum is the Taylor series expansion of $e^x$:
$$e^x = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!}$$
In our case, $x = e^s λt$. So:
$$M_{N(t)}(s) = e^{-\lambda t} \cdot e^{e^s \lambda t}$$
$$M_{N(t)}(s) = e^{-\lambda t + e^s \lambda t} = e^{\lambda t(e^s - 1)}$$
The variance can also be defined relative to moments.
The mean $ E[N(t)] $ is the first derivative of the MGF evaluated at $ s = 0 $:
$$
     E[N(t)] = M'_{N(t)}(0) = \frac{d}{ds} e^{\lambda t (e^s - 1)} \bigg|_{s=0}
    $$
$$
     = \lambda t \cdot e^0 \cdot e^{\lambda t (e^0 - 1)} = \lambda t
    $$
The second moment $ E[N(t)^2] $ is obtained from the second derivative of the MGF:
$$
     E[N(t)^2] = M''_{N(t)}(0) = \frac{d^2}{ds^2} e^{\lambda t (e^s - 1)} \bigg|_{s=0}
    $$
$$
     = (\lambda t)^2 + \lambda t
    $$
Thus, the  variance is:
$$
     \text{Var}[N(t)] = E[N(t)^2] - (E[N(t)])^2
    $$
$$
     = (\lambda t)^2 + \lambda t - (\lambda t)^2 = \lambda t
    $$
I am not sure how to solve Question 2.
As a simulation exercise - for a specific set of parameter values, I can numerically simulate this. For example, for a Poisson Process with $\lambda=0.5$, I can find out the relationship between the time required and probability needed to observe 23 events (note: this was done using R and I can share my code if anyone is interested):

But how can I solve this mathematically?
After doing some reading online, I think that Question 2 might correspond to the Erlang Distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_distribution). I wrote the PDF and CDF for the Erlang Distribution (the time needed for the $k^{th}$ event to happen in a Poisson Process):
$$f(x; k, \lambda) = \frac{\lambda^k x^{k-1} e^{-\lambda x}}{(k-1)!}, \quad x \geq 0$$
$$F(t; k, \lambda) = 1 - e^{-\lambda t} \sum_{n=0}^{k-1} \frac{(\lambda t)^n}{n!}$$
In our case (i.e. $k$ and $\lambda$ are known), I think we should be able to adapt the CDF like this:
$$P(T \leq t) = p_1$$
$$1 - e^{-\lambda t} \sum_{n=0}^{22} \frac{(\lambda t)^n}{n!} = p_1$$
I am not sure if the above equation has an exact solution. I think the above equation can be numerically solved and this will give us the desired answer for Question 2.
Can someone let me know if I am on the right track?
Much Appreciated!


Note: Relationship between Poisson Process and Erlang Distribution

Find the distribution of the time $T_k$ until the $k^{th}$ event occurs.
If we say that $T_k > t$, it means that at most $k-1$ events happened before time $t$.
$$ P(T_k > t) = P(\text{fewer than } k \text{ events in time } t) $$
In a Poisson process, the number of events in time t follows a Poisson distribution:
$$ P(N(t) = n) = \frac{(\lambda t)^n e^{-\lambda t}}{n!} $$
Therefore,
$$ P(T_k > t) = \sum_{n=0}^{k-1} P(N(t) = n) = \sum_{n=0}^{k-1} \frac{(\lambda t)^n e^{-\lambda t}}{n!} $$
The CDF of $T_k$ is:
$$ F_{T_k}(t) = P(T_k \leq t) = 1 - P(T_k > t) = 1 - \sum_{n=0}^{k-1} \frac{(\lambda t)^n e^{-\lambda t}}{n!} $$
Step 5: To get the PDF, we differentiate the CDF:
$$ f_{T_k}(t) = \frac{d}{dt} F_{T_k}(t) = \frac{d}{dt} \left(1 - e^{-\lambda t} \sum_{n=0}^{k-1} \frac{(\lambda t)^n}{n!}\right) $$
$$ f_{T_k}(t) = \lambda e^{-\lambda t} \frac{(\lambda t)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!} $$
And this is exactly the Erlang Distribution.
Thus we can see that the time of the $k^{th}$ event in a Poisson Process follows the Erlang Distribution.

To be clear, are you looking for the lowest $t$ such that $\mathbb P[N(t)\geq k] =p_1$?

@Wei: Yes, exactly!

You want the lowest $t$ such that $\mathbb P[N(t)\geq k] =p_1$. This is equivalent to
$$F_{\lambda t}(k-1)=1-p_1$$
Where $F_{\lambda t}$ is the CDF of a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda t$, and you can look up the formula for this CDF on e.g. Wikipedia. Then solve for $t$, though I can't promise that there's a closed-form solution. It's likely equivalent to the expression you have based on the Erlang distribution.

Thank you @Wei! I was looking at this yesterday and it seems (assuming I am correct) that in the example I made (i.e. 23 events) - solving this would result in a root finding problem for a 22nd degree polynomial! :)
